# Linux - Java/File encoding

Tags: java, linux, encoding, debian, bukkit

I've searched around the web a while now and haven't found anything giving me a proper answer.

I've got a linux server running debian and a bukkit server, I've rusn my server on windows before and my files seems to go right with UTF-8 encoding. I uploaded my files via winscp and now they seems to be ASCII or something else. Because ingame and also in the files every special char, like umlauts changed to placeholders and ingame to questionmarks.
I've tried to change encoding of a file (would be hard to do this for every file... asspecially if I need to to that everytime uploading a new one) but it only changed to a single questionmark instead of these placeholder stuff.
For jenkins I needed to change encoding via encoding=... in the javac execution in my build.xml but I don't know any flag to change encoding for the java cmd.

I also read it should be possible to change the encoding for the whole java but the tried cmds didn't worked at all.

I would be happy to get some tips how to fix this or in general how to avoid converting every file I upload...

Thank you very much :)

~Julian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

`java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 *.jar`

to run a java project in specific encoding no matter what default encoding the current system use.

if you intend to **change all files in a project to a specific encoding** in eclipse

right click on your project in project explorer -> Properties(or Alt+Enter) -> Resource -> look on the right, you can see **Text File Encoding**, Then you can choose UTF-8 as needed.

**Remember to check all your packages**(right click and check Text File Encoding part) **that they all inherited from container.**

Hope this help!

Comment: thank you that worked perfectly, but now I need to know how to change all files to UTF-8 or generally set the encoding of files to utf-8

Comment: I think you missunderstood me, I've config files of type YAML and I upload them with winscp they are never in eclipse. After the upload there encoding seems to be changed. I want change the genreal encoding in my linux os or prevent winscp from change it.